# Inserting arrays into a sql

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have this problem with my code that has been bugging me for a couple of days. I am trying to do a project where my user can request a delivery where he can choose a set of items according to what he needs. Thing is when I pass the data into the array it only captures the first line and ignores the rest.

Since I'm here, if possible can anyone help me find a way to insert the data I get into sql. This is the code I have at the moment

```
<?php
$sql="select * from Material_Equipamento";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$sql2="select * from Fornecedores";
$res2=mysql_query($sql2);
?>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h4 align="center"> Formulário Encomenda</h4>
<form  class="form-inline" role="form" align="center" method="POST" action="index.php?cmd=ins-enc">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label " for="dp">Data do Pedido:</label> 
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="dp" value="" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label " for="de">Data de Entrega:</label> 
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="de" value="" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label " for="f">Fornecedor :</label> 
<select class="form-control" id="forn" name='forn'>
<?php
while ($lin2=mysql_fetch_array($res2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  echo "<option value='";
  echo $lin2['n_Fornecedor'];
  echo "'>";
  echo $lin2['Nome'];
  echo "</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th class="text-center">Material</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Quantidade</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Valor previsto por Unidade</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0' data-id="0" >
                    <td data-name="mat">
                        <select class="form-control" name="mat[]">
                            <?php
                            while ($lin=mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                            echo "<option value='";
                            echo $lin['n_Mat_Equip'];
                            echo "'>";
                            echo $lin['Nome'];
                            echo "</option>";
                         }
?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td data-name="quant">
                        <input type="text" name='quant[]' placeholder='Quantidade' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-name="Valuni">
                        <input type="text" name='valuni[]' placeholder='Valor Previsto por Unidade' class="form-control"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-name="del">
                        <button nam"del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Outro item</a>

<br><input type="submit" value="Adicionar Material">
<input type="reset" value="Limpar ecrã">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's the form and the php to get something from my tables, I also have this script running so the user can add more items as he wishes.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
            newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
        }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
        id: "addr"+newid,
        "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
        var cur_td = $(this);

        var children = cur_td.children();

        // add new td and element if it has a nane
        if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
            });

            var c =     $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
            c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
            c.appendTo($(td));
            td.appendTo($(tr));
        } else {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
            }).appendTo($(tr));
        }
    });

    // add delete button and td
    /*
    $("<td></td>").append(
        $("<button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>")
            .click(function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            })
    ).appendTo($(tr));
    */

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});




// Sortable Code
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();

    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });

    return $helper;
};

$(".table-sortable tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified      
}).disableSelection();

$(".table-sortable thead").disableSelection();



$("#add_row").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

I don't understand where the problem is at =/ I know its alot of code so sorry if any of you end up reading it all. But yeah the problem is it only reads the predefined row that appears right away when u enter the page, but doesn't read the others that the user adds. Thank you for your cooperation =). By the way I use bootstrap for the visuals in case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing brackets in your javascript code when you duplicate the fields. Try this :

```js
// loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
        var cur_td = $(this);

        var children = cur_td.children();

        // add new td and element if it has a nane
        if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
            });
  
            var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
   //Test if the initial field have brackets and is define...
   if($(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).attr('name') != undefined){
                //Is there bracket?
    if( $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).attr('name').indexOf('[') != -1){
     c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid + '[]');
    }else{
     c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
    }
   }else{
    c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
   }
   
            c.appendTo($(td));
            td.appendTo($(tr));
        } else {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
            }).appendTo($(tr));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing. Thing is my main problem is that after reading the first row which is already there when the user loads the page, it completly fails to read the rest of the rows. And yes even after adding your changes it still doesn't read them, thanks for the attention though =)

Comment: Fixed it. After searching throught the code a bit I figured out my problem was I was changing the name of the input every time it creted a new item entry, so the array was not recognizable. Thank you for the help though =)

Comment: mysql extension is deprecated. You should migrate for mysqli : there are few differences.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind @Portekoi. I'v been using mysql extension because I was thought to use it, but I'm working on changing the mysql part now =) Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I see you are still using mysql_* functions, they are deprecated I advice you to switch to mysqli_* functions or PDO. I suggest you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php if you want to stick at mysql_* functions otherwise I have a PDO solution:

**Query Part**

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$query = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM Material_Equipamento');
$materials = $query->fetchAll();
$query = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM Fornecedores');
$results = $query->fetchAll();
?>
```

You'll need this links:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

**Foreach Loop**

```
<?php
foreach($materials as $material)
{
  ?>
  <option value="<?=$material['n_Mat_Equip'];?>"><?=$material['Nome'];?></option>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Ill be sure to study a bit more then ;P I just started programming a while ago so there's alot of stuff I don't know =)